# tinymce3 editor in joomla 1.5 browse button not working

Tags: callback, tinymce, joomla1.5

i have a strange issue i have a joomla 1.5 site and i have installed the tinymce3 cause the client needs really bad this button that it has ,,that is the paste from word,, the problem is that when i insert for example a link or an image then when i click the browse button to browse files and content then **nothing happens** with the onclick,, :(

i have searched through the net and found MCImageManager might be a solution but i have to buy it.. is there any other way ?
any help would be really appreciated,

thank you guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys in case someone else need it,

just instead of tinymce editor i used the jce editor,

solved just from the jce editor it provides this kind of functionality the paste from word

just by playing on the default profile plugging settings parameters

and the browse button is working like a charm,

once again thank you